# Testflight taking some time to assign internal group for testing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm experience delay since last week for Testflight to assign internal group for testing.(Within an hour its automatically added). When I tried to manually add groups to the build, It's greyed out (disabled).

Anyone knows the reason for this?

Note: Usually the build is automatically available on the testflight after processing finished.

[image]

**Update**: Apple took exactly 30m for this.

Comment: I'm having the same issue over the last 2 days, but I can tell you that the internal groups is greyed out because builds are supposed to be automatically assigned to that group and you cannot manually assign them.  I pushed up another build and it immediately sent out the previous stuck build to the internal test group.

Comment: Same issue here...gonna give it an hour or two and then try pushing another build

Comment: Looks like it was just a timing thing for me...after an hour or two the internal testing group was automatically added and users were notified

Comment: Update: Apple took exactly 30m for this.

Answer (score 0):

Select "Test Information" from the left side menu and fill in the required information. Check again after 10 minutes. It will now be added.

Comment: That's not working. I believe apple added some cool-off time (30min) for this.